# handling gui events MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is kinda weird question to ask, but all I need are some guidelines. I am learning c# more seriously and I came across one problem that is bothering me. When you have for example event triggered on gui button click you have auto generated event method in there you call things you need to do. However I think if you want to follow good MVC practice you should keep Model and logic separated from view. So how is this done in more professional ways? How can I avoid running logic or event instance creation in button event handler ? (I can write logic in some other classes you may think, but then I need to create instance of this object in event handler, which for me is just ugly) What are some design patterns to solve this?

Comment: The button falls into the "C" category of MVC. Controllers manipulate the model.

Comment: you are actually right...But is this a good practice to create new instances there and then modify them? what about if you want to keep model on different thread that view...wouldnt that be a problem?

Comment: I think you're confused a little bit. MVC does not rely on server-side events like WebForms does. If you're talking WebForms, you're better off using an MVP approach.